# use topic's variable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I want to use the variable which I subscribe on my code program.
what can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233128/use-topic%27s-variable/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-04-28**:
What do you mean exactly? From what you say, it seems that you must read again the tutorials

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-28**:
i subscribe to a std_msgs/Float64 variable all is ok.
now, i want to use this variable on my code like x = this variable, but i don't know how to convert it.
have you any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[`x = variable.data`](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64.html)

For more details about the type itself check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/205541/what-is-float64/)

In your case, variable has the type `std_msgs::Float64` . `variable.data` would be just a double. declare x as double.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-28**:
yes but which type i use for x?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-04-28**:
If you ask this question I guess you are using C++?

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-28**:
yes, i use C++.
I try to use std_msgs::Float64 x;
x=variable.data;
but it doesn't work

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-04-28**:
variable has the type std_msgs::Float64 . variable.data would be just a double. declare x as double. And put a code example in your question, including the declaration of the subscriber and of the callback function, that would help.